# Hibernate queries for @JoinColumn and mappedBy

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to understand the differences in the DML queries generated if I use @JoinColumn compared to mappedBy attribute of @OneToMany mapping in Hibernate.

If I have my java classes defined as:

```
@Entity
public class Product {
  @Id
  String serialNumber;
  @OneToMany
  @JoinColumn(name = "PRODUCT_ID")
  Set<Part> parts = new HashSet<Part>();
}

@Entity
public class Part {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    int id;
    String partName;
}
```

Then id I save a Product and Parts then hibernate generates inserts and also update queries:

```
Hibernate: insert into Product (serialNumber) values (?)
Hibernate: insert into Part (partName, id) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: update Part set PRODUCT_ID=? where id=?
```

Now if I have my java classes defined as:

```
@Entity
public class Customer {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "customer")
    private List<Order> orders;
}

@Entity
@Table(name="TBL_ORDER")
public class Order {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;
    private int orderNumber;
    @ManyToOne
    private Customer customer;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return id.toString();
    }
}
```

Then Hibernate generates only insert queries without any updates:

```
Hibernate: insert into Customer (id) values (?)
Hibernate: insert into TBL_ORDER (customer_id, orderNumber, id) values (?, ?, ?)
```

If my relationship between entities is only one-to-many then why hibernate needs insert & updates for first case and only insert queries in second case? Please explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first version that uses `@JoinColumn`, you need to persist `Part` first before  `Product`, for example:

```
Part part1 = new Part()
Part part2 = new Part()
em.persist(part1)
em.persist(part2)
Product product = new Product()
product.parts.add(part1)
product.parts.add(part2)
em.persist(product)
```

When persisting `part1` and `part2`, Hibernate generates insert SQL for `Part`.  Hibernate doesn't know what is the `id` for `Product` yet so `PRODUCT_ID` column will be null.

When persisting `product`, Hibernate generates insert SQL for `Product`.  Now Hibernate knows what is the generated `id` for `Product`.  Hibernate then issue update SQL to update existing record for `Part`by setting the appropriate value for `PRODUCT_ID` column.

In the second version that uses `mappedBy`, you're persisting them like:

```
Customer customer = new Customer()
em.persist(customer)
Order order1 = new Order()  // using `Order` as entity name is not always valid because `Order` it is often confused with SQL clause
order1.setCustomer(customer)
em.persist(order1)
Order order2 = new Order()
order2.setCustomer(customer)
em.persist(order2)
```

The difference is when you persisting `order1` and `order2`, you're telling Hibernate what is the `Customer` for that `Order`.  The id for the related customer is saved in each orders.

If you want to have something like the first version with `@JoinColumn` but without extra updates SQL, you can use `@ElementCollection`, for example:

```
@Entity
public class Product {
  @Id @GeneratedValue
  String serialNumber;

  @ElementCollection
  Set<Part> parts = new HashSet<Part>();
}

@Entity
public class Part {
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    int id;

    String partName;
}
```

The mapping above will generate an extra relation table such as `product_part`.